# Android service boot order

Tags: java, android

Greetings, I am writing an application that will be utilizing a service that needs to be started before any other services listening for the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast can start. After some cursory searching I have not found anything that would imply an ability to control the boot order. Is this something that can be accomplished via the java application SDK or will I need to start messing around with lower level code? This is for a legitimate security application and I have root access if needed.

Comment: And it would also be nice if I could hold off on having my service be killed until all other services are killed.

Comment: I'm assuming that "any other services" means "any other services of any other application", right?

Comment: Yes, I am writing something that will be profiling applications and as such I would like to make sure that my profiler service is running before any services that we might be potentially attempting to observe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. In order to be able to control the order, the Broadcast should be an Ordered Broadcast (more on this [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html)).

The best chance you have is to check if it's ordered (you can check this using [`isOrderedBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#isOrderedBroadcast%28%29) in your Receiver), and then if it is, control the order using the priority attribute.

Comment: ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is an unordered broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a priority on the BOOT_COMPLETED IntentFilter?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet, still researching :) I'll look into that, though.